# Sklearn TypeError: init() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tol'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have sklearn version 0.18.1 installed. I get this error message. Have recently re-installed anaconda. I am trying to run this:

```
   sgd = SGDClassifier(tol=1e3,max_iter=100,penalty='elasticnet',class_weight='balanced',shuffle=True)
   pipeline = make_pipeline(cv, tfidf, sgd)
```

> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tol'

Comment: tol is not an argument of SGDClassifier in version 0.18.1. See the documentation for it at http://scikit-learn.org/0.18/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier

Answer (score 1):

Because it was introduced in version `0.19`. This is where they mention it in the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html) taken straight from sklearn -

> tol : float or None, optional The stopping criterion. If it is not
>   None, the iterations will stop when (loss > previous_loss - tol).
>   Defaults to None. Defaults to 1e-3 from 0.21.
>
> New in version 0.19.

**EDIT:**
[This](http://scikit-learn.org/0.18/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html) is the documentation for your version of sklearn.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected, as [sgdclassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html) says:

> tol : float or None, optional The stopping criterion. If it is not
>   None, the iterations will stop when (loss > previous_loss - tol).
>   Defaults to None. Defaults to 1e-3 from 0.21.
>
> New in version 0.19.

So if you use 0.18.1, then it may not recognise it.